# Disabling plugins in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I installed some plugins for Eclipse and now when it stops while loading giving the non responsive window in Ubuntu. Can I disable the plugins or uninstall them without running eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your plugin directory form Eclipse/plugins/ and start your eclipse.

Comment: Remove your plugins jars from plugin folder & feature project.